# Limit of the series $\sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{3k-4}{3k+2}) ^{\frac{k+1}{3}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Whether the series is convergent or divergent.

My approach:
consider $a_n=(\frac{3k-4}{3k+2}) ^{\frac{k+1}{3}}$.

Now $\log a_n= \frac{k+1}{3}[ \log (3k-4)-\log(3k+2)]$.

Here $(a_n)$ is a function from N$\rightarrow$ R. Therefore it is continuous. So by composite function theorem and l'Hospital rule, $\lim a_n$=1. Therefore the series is not convergent.

Am I right? **Is there any other way to check the convergence of this series?**

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Do you mean $\log a_n\to 0$? I'm afraid it's false.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Cube roots are defined for negative numbers; what's the problem?

Comment: @Bernard Why it is false. Could you please explain

Comment: @CloudJR: That's because $\;\log(3n-4)-\log(3n+2)=-\dfrac2n+o\Bigl(\dfrac1n\Bigr)$, so $\;\log a_n\sim_\infty\dfrac n3\cdot\dfrac2n=\dfrac23$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm just giving it a try
$$\begin{align}a_n&=\left(\dfrac{3n-4}{3n+2}\right)^{\frac{n+1}3}\\\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}(a_n)&=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\left[\left(1-\dfrac6{3n+2}\right)^{3n+2}\right]^{\frac1{3n+2}\cdot\frac{n+1}3}\\&=(e^{-6})^{\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{9n+6}}\\&=e^{-\frac23}\end{align}$$

Since $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}a_n\neq0$, hence the series diverges by $n^{\text{th}}$ term test.

Comment: Since an ≠ 0 or since limit of an is ≠ 0 ?

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani fixed